# starting with mkmap and need to show real time route between two points

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, mkmapview

I am new to ios development and I am Developing a iphone app in which i need to use mkmapview.
In this i need to show route between two or more pin points.

please help for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to draw pins on `MKMapView`. Here i have used **San Francisco** city's two near locations points.

```
- (void) setDirectionLocation {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.79520324238053, -122.40283370018005);
    MKCoordinateRegion region;

    region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.02, 0.02));
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
    [self.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D toCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.802932, -122.401612);

    MKPlacemark *fromPlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:location addressDictionary:nil];
    MKPlacemark *toPlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:toCoordinate addressDictionary:nil];

    MKMapItem *fromItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:fromPlacemark];
    MKMapItem *toItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:toPlacemark];

    MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
    request.source = fromItem;
    request.destination = toItem;
    request.requestsAlternateRoutes = YES;


    MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             MKRoute *route = response.routes[0];
             [self.mapView addOverlay:route.polyline];

             // Drop a pin
             MKPointAnnotation *startPin = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
             startPin.coordinate = location;
             startPin.title = @"Start";
             [self.mapView addAnnotation:startPin];

             MKPointAnnotation *endPin = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
             endPin.coordinate = toCoordinate;
             endPin.title = @"End";
             [self.mapView addAnnotation:endPin];
         } else {
             NSLog(@"direction not found.");
         }
     }];
}
```